# In AEM, DAM Update Asset Workflow is not getting executed for videos?

Tags: aem, video-encoding, dam

When I am uploading a mp4 mime type video in AEM, then DAM update asset workflow is not getting executed. Do anyone has idea why it is happening because when I am checking launchers then I am able to see the workflow launcher is enabled for videos also. Can it be the case that for videos only "Dynamic Media Video Encoder" workflow executes. And if it is the case then how can I listen to workflow completed event for "Dynamic Media Video Encoder" workflow completion as I have to include a custom code on completion of video processing.

Comment: Might the mime-type be relevant or any other property of the payload?

Comment: You can modify the DAM update asset workflow according to your requirement.